# When I add a link to a table cell another table is created

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-10.x

I created a website using TYPO3 version 10.4.21. TYPO3 uses the CKEditor as rich text editor.

On one page I need to display many links because it's a summary of archive documents. For that I created a table inside the RTE, each cell contains the doc-name.

The problem is when I create a link on the doc-name it will automatically create another table inside the cell around the text. As my tables are styled it will mess up the whole design. How can I disable that?

I can confirm as NextThursday said that the error only occurs if there is only one word in the cell or if I select the whole cell.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="t3://file?uid=306">Doc1</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td>Doc2</td>
        <td>Doc3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

These are the only configurations I made to the CKEditor:

```html
imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor_image/Configuration/RTE/Plugin.yaml" }

editor:
  externalPlugins:
    indent:
      resource: "EXT:layout/Resources/Public/RTE/Plugins/indent/plugin.js"
    indentblock:
      resource: "EXT:layout/Resources/Public/RTE/Plugins/indentblock/plugin.js"
  
  config:
    externalPlugins:
    - indent
    - indentblock
    removePlugins: null
processing:
    allowAttributes: [class, id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, itemscope, itemtype, itemprop, style]
```

Comment: I can confirm that for TYPO3 9, too. I always thought it was a stupid config on my part. However this only happens here if the table cell has exactly one word in it or rather if the complete table cell content is marked for linking.
 
The current help for editors is to add an additional word in the cell, create the link for the original content, delete the additional word.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your error neither in TYPO3 v9 nor in TYPO3 v10. Can you please update your question and post your CKEditor configuration?